# I can't seem to pass on an object to another class in Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an object which I want to pass to a new frame through a method in another frame class. I found a solution that looked similar to what I was after and tried it, however, the object doesn't get passed. In fact, I got an error message saying "Value after * must be an iterable, not PackingList", where PackingList is the class which the object is made out of. I tried to instead get the "name" attribute of the object and pass it to the next frame, but it just returns an empty tuple. I am really stuck and I appreciate some help.

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Homescreen, Menuscreen, Create, ShowUpcoming, ShowAll, OpenList, Search, Edit):

            frame = F(container, self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Homescreen)

    def show_frame(self, container, *args, **kwargs):

        frame = self.frames[container]
        frame.tkraise()
```

...

```
class ShowAll(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text = "Alla packningslistor", font = ("Times new roman", 30)).place(x = 110, y = 0)
        self.controller = controller
        objectList = PK.main()
        objectOpen = PK.showAll(objectList)

        self.radiobutton_list = []
        self.objectList = objectList

        for i in range(len(objectOpen)):
            radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = objectOpen[i], command = functools.partial(self.objectToOpen, idx = i)).place(x = 150, y = 100 + i*30)
            self.radiobutton_list.append(radiobutton)
    
    def objectToOpen(self, idx):
        
        objectID = self.objectList[idx]
        
        
        return self.controller.show_frame(OpenList, *objectID)
```

```
class OpenList(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *objectID):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #lala = getattr(objectID, "name")
        #print(lala)
```

As I said I tried to pass just the name of the object but it prints out as an empty tuple in the next frame class.

Comment: Change `*objectID` to just `objectID`

Comment: @Barmar, I don't quite understand. I tried switching all the variations of switching *objectID to objectID but I only got different errors like "missing one required positional argument 'objectID'", and in the case where I passed objectID instad of *objectID in the function objectToOpen, I again got an empty tuple.

Comment: I'm just talking about this line: `self.controller.show_frame(OpenList, *objectID)` `objectID` isn't a list, you can't spread it with `*`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the answer again. I tried it and now it returns an empty tuple when I try to print it in the new frame.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with how you created the frames in the `App` class. `objectID` is just the index of a frame in `self.frames`, it has no effect on the contents.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right. I can't figure out what it is but I will take a closer at the class App. Thanks.

Comment: Even you have passed extra arguments to `show_frame()` function but they are not used inside that function.

Comment: You wrote `for F in (Homescreen, Menuscreen, Create, ShowUpcoming, ShowAll, OpenList, Search, Edit)` . Should not `Homescreen`, `Menuscreen`, ... etc be `str` objects instead of being undefined objects? You are using them as keywords of a `dict` object in `self.frames`. Also, `frame = F(container, self, *args, **kwargs)` is wrong as F is a `str` object.

Comment: You are using `pack` and `grid` on `container`. You can't do that as you can only either use `pack` or `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question. But here are my corrections to your `App` class. I hope these corrections can help your understanding of Python and tkinter and debug the rest of your codes.

If you need more detailed help, it will be helpful if you can more specific by stating in the comment section what you want to do with classes `App`, `ShowAll`, and `OpenList` (or their method), and I will see how I can help you by elaborating my answer further.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.container = tk.Frame(self)
    self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    self.frames = {}
    colors = ('white', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'magenta')
    frames = ("Homescreen", "Menuscreen", "Create", "ShowUpcoming", "ShowAll", "OpenList", "Search", "Edit")
    col=0
    for C, F in zip(colors, frames):
        print(f'{F=}')
        self.frames[F] = tk.Frame(self.container, background=C, width=100, height=50)
        self.frames[F].grid(row=0, column=col, sticky="nsew")
        # col += 1   # uncomment this to see all frames
    self.show_frame('Create')  # you should see red

def show_frame(self, container):
    self.frames[container].tkraise()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```